# Is there a way to not create specific tag for specific row in the xml for null or None value in the pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, xml, dataframe, null

I have null and None in the dataframe.
I want to to create xml out of the dataframe by to_xml method.
Now, in xml, there are tags that contain null or none. I don't need those tags if value of tag is null or None.
One way is to parse the created xml and remove the specific tag from the row but this will complicate the processing as writing and then reading and again writing will take place.

Is there a way that I can handle it all while creating xml so I write/create xml only once?

I tried this and it is working (only for None) but as you can see, its working like

- Create XML from Dataframe
- Read XML
- Transform XML
- Again Create Dataframe
- Again Create XML

```
sourcedf.to_xml(path_or_buffer=sourcexml.xml)
with open(path_of_source_xml, 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
root = etree.fromstring(data.encode())
for element in root.xpath(".//*[not(node())]"):
    element.getparent().remove(element)
byteObjectToString= etree.tostring(root)
df = pd.read_xml(byteObjectToString)

df.to_xml(path_or_buffer=finalXML\\finalWriteXML.xml",index=False,root_name='listings',row_name='listing',na_rep='')
```

Primary : I want to do all of it from sourcedf and then create the final XML without creating source xml. Secondary :  Can I incorporate null condition to it as well?

Sample:
source Data:

```
<Items>
    <Name>Hello</Name>
    <Cost>9.99</Cost>
    <Condition/>
    <Plan/>
</Items>
```

Target Expected:

```
<Items>
    <Name>Hello</Name>
    <Cost>9.99</Cost>
</Items>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `parent.remove(child)`. For that you need a `(parent, child) map`.

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# Preparation for a working example
columns = ["Name","Cost","Condition","Plan"]
data = [["Hello","9.99","",""]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
print(df)
print()

# Export xml string
xml = df.to_xml(root_name='root', row_name='Items', index=False)
print(xml)
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
print(root)
print()

def rem (rem_list, root):
    """ Remove listed empty tags from root"""
    parent_map = {(c, p) for p in root.iter( ) for c in p}
    print("\nParent, Child map:\n",[(c.tag, p.tag) for (c,p) in parent_map])
    for (c, p) in parent_map:
        if c.tag in rem_list:
            p.remove(c)
    print("\nEmpty tags removed from tree:")
    ET.dump(root)

# Collect empty tag, which would like removed
rem_list = []
for empty_tag in root.iter():
    if empty_tag.text == None:
        rem_list.append(empty_tag.tag)
print("\nEmpty tags:",rem_list)
# Call remove function
rem(rem_list, root)
```

I don't know if `to_xml()` from pandas have a option.

Input:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<root>
  <Items>
    <Name>Hello</Name>
    <Cost>9.99</Cost>
    <Condition/>
    <Plan/>
  </Items>
</root>
```

Output (xml dump of the function):

```
<root>
  <Items>
    <Name>Hello</Name>
    <Cost>9.99</Cost>
  </Items>
</root>
```